# URI malformed, cannot be parsed - while connecting to mongdb using MongoDB Compass connection string

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to connect to mongoDB with the new password with special char as shown in the screenshot. It gives error as URL malformed due to special character in it.

Initially I was able to connect with normal password.

I tried to add escape characters in password with no luck.

Does anybody have came across this situations or know the solution? Any leads highly appreciated[![enter image description here][1]][1]. Thanks.

Comment: Try URL encoding the special characters

Answer (score 1):

Click on the ***Fill in connection fields individually*** then input the fields.
It will create the URI with escaped characters for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your password includes special characters you need to encode all special characters. you can find it on this link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp